# UART Transmit issue in VHDL

Tags: vhdl, uart, digital-communications

I'm working on a UART transmit process `(uart_transmit)` in VHDL (115200 baud, 8 data bits, 1 stop bit and no parity). I need the transmit line `(tx_line)` in the process to go idle whenever the carriage return `(CARR_RET)` in the message buffer is detected.

The buffer is part of another process but it shifts each character into `char_byte` when the transmission of the last byte has finished. It is clocked by the `TX_DONE` signal.

The issue I'm having, however, is that the FPGA transmits the entire message as required except for the carriage return. I know it's because the process `uart_ready` detects the carriage return and changes the state of `TX_READY` accordingly but I don't know how to workaround the instantaneous change, I thought about delaying the `TX_READY` signal with an FDC but that didn't work. Are there any suggestions as to how I can detect the carriage return, transmit the carriage return and still send the transmit line to idle?

```
library IEEE;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_1164.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_ARITH.ALL;
use IEEE.STD_LOGIC_UNSIGNED.ALL;
use IEEE.NUMERIC_STD;

entity uart_tx is
        Port (clk               : in std_logic;
                    reset           : in std_logic;
                    tx_line         : out std_logic;
                    switch          : in std_logic;
                    TX_DONE         : out std_logic;
                    char_byte       : in std_logic_vector(7 downto 0));
end uart_tx;

architecture Behavioral of uart_tx is

constant stop_bit       : std_logic :='1';
constant start_bit      : std_logic :='0';
constant idle           : std_logic :='1';
constant CARR_RET       : std_logic_vector(7 downto 0) :="00001010";

signal  TX_READY    : std_logic :='0';
signal  TX_MESSAGE  : std_logic_vector(9 downto 0) :=(others => '0');

begin
uart_ready: process (clk,reset)
 begin
    if(reset='1') then
        TX_READY<='0';
    elsif rising_edge(clk)then 
        if(switch = '1')then
            if(char_byte = CARR_RET)then
                TX_READY<='0';
            else
                TX_READY<='1';
            end if;
        end if;
    end if;
 end process;

uart_transmit: process (clk,reset)
 variable bit_count: integer range 0 to 9:=0;
 begin
    if(reset='1') then
        tx_line<=idle;
        bit_count:=0;
        TX_DONE<='0';
        TX_MESSAGE<="0000000000";
        elsif rising_edge(clk)then 
            if(switch = '1')then
                TX_MESSAGE(9 downto 0) <= stop_bit &char_byte &start_bit;

                if(TX_READY = '1')then
                 if(bit_count=9)then
                    TX_MESSAGE<="0000000000";
                    TX_DONE<='1';
                    tx_line<=idle;
                    bit_count:=0;
                 else 
                    tx_line<=TX_MESSAGE(bit_count);
                    bit_count:= bit_count+1;
                    TX_DONE<='0';
                 end if;
                elsif(TX_READY = '0')then
                 tx_line<=idle;
                end if;
          end if;
        end if;
 end process;
end Behavioral;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the process to go idle whenever the carriage return (CARR_RET) in the message buffer is detected.

If you look at the above carefully your should notice that your specification is already wrong. The correct specification would be:
*"the process to go idle after the carriage return (CARR_RET) has been sent."*

That means detect a CR has been loaded in the the transmitter and the transmitter has sent it.

Next you try to solve this by adapting your existing logic. I would not do that. Instead I would keep that functionality separated from the other functions and add a small FSM to specifically deal with the issue:

1. Idle state, goto 2 if a CR has been loaded in the
   transmit register.
2. Goto 3 if the transmit register has started shifting out.
3. Goto 4 if the transmitter finishes. set line to not-ready.
4. Wait for a 'goto idle' signal, set line to ready.

In state 4 you need some condition on which the FSM is reset again, but you did not talk about that part of the protocol in your question.

---

Your  comment:

> Is there any particular reason why you wouldn't adapt the existing logic?

is a good one so I'll answer it here:

Experience has shown me code is easier to understand, debug and maintain if you keep functionality separated. In fact you are doing that already as you have a separate process for the READY.
Now all you need to do is make that process a bit more intelligent by keeping better track of what is happening, which is like the sort of FSM I suggested.

> Also, the FSM would be reset when the message buffer has a new message loaded into it

That is not the right way. A reset is there to set an initial state. Sending the next character should **not** require you to use the reset. I consider that sloppy and the easy-way out.

In a real chip the reset goes everywhere on start-up and now you are going to have to add some 'or' functionality to reset the block also when a character needs to be sent. 
Your company's Design-For-Test engineer will give you a firm talk-to for that as it will play havoc with his scan-chains.

Furthermore you reset is asynchronous which can cause glitches in all logic down the chain. If you really want to use a reset use at least a synchronous one.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you wouldn't adapt the existing logic? Also, the FSM would be reset when the message buffer has a new message loaded into it.